# Add Error and Success Handler for HTTP Request

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I have a login page which makes a request to a URL and posts variables or the Username and Password to the URL, then upon completion takes me to a new View Controller.

When I put in the right Username and Password the request works , cause I can copy the html in the Log it shows me my profile that I made the request to.

If I put in the wrong details and I copy the html, I get the Login page html from the Log or console.

How would I only direct the user to the New View Controller or Modal TabBar when the correct details are put in.

I want to show an error if the wrong details are entered.

Many thanks

**LoginTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
UITabBarController *tbc;
}

- (void)dismissTabBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tbc;

@end
```

**LoginTableViewController.m**

```
#import "LoginTableViewController.h"
#import "rootViewController.h"

@interface LoginTableViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UIEmailTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UIPasswordTextField;

@end

@implementation LoginTableViewController
@synthesize UIEmailTextField;
@synthesize UIPasswordTextField;
@synthesize tbc;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setUIEmailTextField:nil];
[self setUIPasswordTextField:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - barButton Outlet

- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",UIEmailTextField.text, UIPasswordTextField.text];
NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

// preaparing URL request to send data.

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://online.vrmcapital.co.za"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:7.0];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Login response:%@",str);

NSLog(@"Log In button was pressed!");


NSLog(@"Tab Bar Controller Button Clicked");
UIViewController *blueController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
blueController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
blueController.title = @"Blue";
blueController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery.png"];

UIViewController *redController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
redController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 140.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
[button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTabBar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[redController.view addSubview:button];
//redController.title = @"Red1";
[redController setTitle:@"Red1" ];
redController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery.png"];
image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery.png"];


tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:blueController, redController, nil];
tbc.selectedViewController = redController;
NSLog(@"Selected index = %d of %d", tbc.selectedIndex, [tbc.viewControllers count]);

//[blueController release];
//[redController release];
[self presentViewController:tbc animated:YES completion:nil];



}

- (void)dismissTabBar {
[[self tbc] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the server endpoint that your are hitting in your request provides an HTML form whenever your provide an erroneous username or password.  I assume it provides a different HTML page otherwise.

Either way, without a proper web service, you're going have to deal with HTML parsing.  You hope the web developers don't decide to change the pages in ways that break your parser...Again, without a proper web service, you'll have to rely on HTML page parsing to distinguish between successful and unsuccessful requests.

As an aside, do you really want to use the synchronous API of `NSURLConnection` on the main thread?  IF the network connection is poor, your main thread will be blocked.